# How to make responsive flex like Github?

Tags: html, css

I make it for web is good but i need to make it responsive for phones too.
[image]

```css
.features-container, .authentication-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}

.features-container {
    max-width: 900px;
    border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
}
.authentication-container {
    align-items: center !important;
    display: flex !important;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
}
.authentication {
    max-width: 314px;
    border-style: none;
    text-align: right !important;
}
.authentication-title {
    0;
    0;
    color: white !important;
}
.authentication-title, .authentication-sub {
    text-align: left !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .item {
        width: 33.3333333333%;
        text-align: right !important;
        padding: 32px !important;
        flex: 1 1 auto !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center features-container app-screenshot">
                <div class="feature-items">
                        <div class="authentication-container">
                                <div class="item item-right">
                                        <img class="authentication" src="https://desktop.github.com/images/upgrade/co-authoring.png" alt="Authentication">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item item-left">
                                        <h4 class="authentication-title">Attribute commits with collaborators easily</h4>
                                        <p class="authentication-sub">Quickly add co-authors to your commit. Great for pairing and excellent for sending a little love/credit to that special someone who helped fix that gnarly bug of yours. See the attribution on the history page, undo an accidental attribution, and see the co-authors on github.com</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

i want to make like a Github.

Original template: https://desktop.github.com
My Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJXiR.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: there's no errors in code, but i's not responsive for phones.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex-wrap: wrap` is **WORKING**

```css
.authentication-container {
    •••
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` not working i tryed it before share the code.

Comment: **It is working for me** https://imgur.com/a/JokGKLB